# Need help troubleshooting a server connectivity issue

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, vpn

So I'm seeing an issue randomly appearing on some of our servers. Where they will become unreachable by VPN users for no apparent reason. Rebooting the server "fixes" the problem and after reboot they are reachable again.  It is because of the server reboot fixing it, that I am assuming it is an issue with the server(s), but I'm open to other suggestions.
Servers are of more than one version, but mostly 2008 R2 and 2012 R2
Servers are all Dell servers.

So servers will have been working fine, and then out of nowhere they do not respond to any sort of network connectivity from VPN users.  They work just fine from internally connected users.

Windows firewall is turned OFF on the servers, so it's not a Windows Firewall issue.

I haven't been able to find anything in the logs that points to what's happening.  I've looked at increasing the auditing of the logs, but I can't see anything else I should turn on that might help identify the issue.

Aside from the firewall, how else would the server know/care about if the connection is coming from a VPN or internal connection.
The VPN users are on a separate subnet, but we have multiple subnets, and no other subnets are affected.

I'm guessing I'm overlooking something here. So I'm reaching out here for help on how to track this down.
Thanks!

Comment: Turning the local firewall off on a server is generally a very bad idea... Have you checked the open sockets (`netstat`)? Possibly an attacker is using up the maximum number of connections.

Comment: Not seeing anything unusual with netstat, but if it was at max connections, it would not allow a connection from anywhere, I'm only having issues across the VPN connections.

Comment: Does ping still work from a VPN user when a connection is refused? Is a connection refused or does it just time out? Have you tried a packet capture? Have you checked the routing table on the server when it's unreachable?

Comment: Ping does not work when it's happening.
I forget exactly on the response, but I'm pretty sure it was destination unreachable.
Right now it's not having an issue, so I can't check the route table.  What would I look for in the route table?

Comment: Well, the server could some difference in the routing table, a route from invalid ICMP redirection, ... We don't know anything about how your routing is done (static, RIP, OSPF, ...).

Comment: You could also try to enable nating on the vpn clients to eliminate any routing problems on your servers.

Comment: Can you ping the affected server by IP or have you been attempting to ping it by hostname? Also are you using the fully qualified hostname?